# Code line marker in sublime text 2

Tags: notepad++, sublime-text-2, sublime-text

I personally like this feature in notepad++
[image]

Do you know how to do this in Sublime Text 2?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13643964/sublimetext-bookmark-a-line-using-mouse

Answer (score 7):

These are called *Bookmarks* in Sublime Text. Commands related to them are in the *Goto » Bookmarks* menu.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: ah..i see. you have to click ctrl+f2 (for windows). the bookmark doesn't show when you click on the line#. :D thanks for this. :)

Comment: @mars-o Right, that's why I told you where the menu items are and didn't just provide platform-dependent keyboard shortcuts ;-)

Answer (score 2):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> - Toggle bookmark
- <kbd>F2</kbd> - Next bookmark
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> - Persious bookmark
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> - Clear bookmark
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> - Select all bookmarks

Also you can use [Sublime Bookmarks](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Sublime%20Bookmarks) plugin.